# Making a post request to MVC Web API in WinRt?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I've been trying to make a post request to my WebApi.  I'm supposed to send it as Json then the MVC api will convert it into the c# object is supposed to accept.

I use this code in C# to post the data as JSON:

```
 HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
 string postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dbsub);
 StringContent c = new StringContent(postData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 httpClient.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 100000;
 var result = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://127.0.0.1/api/Submissions", c);
```

The problem is in the server the objects properties are returned null.  But Im not getting any errors...

Any idea on how to fix this or is there another way to post c# objects as JSON for MVC Web Api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're lying about the data you POST.

If you serialize the data as JSON, you need to send the correct `Content-Type` of `application/json`.

Comment: I actually did that, but it threw an invalid content type error.

Comment: @HaroldA.Martinez: Apparently, [you need to explicitly set the `ContentType` header](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9863311/34397).

Comment: Ok, got it fix! When I set the content type before and it threw the exception, it was because I wrote it wrong.